# developing a horizontally oriented android app using eclipse

Tags: android, orientation

I want to develop a layout when the device is horizontally oriented .
Providing the Landscape view in the graphical layout of xml file shows it there but not in the emulator..
someone plz help..

Comment: when your rotate your emulator only it will load the xml.

Comment: do you have layout-land folder in res directory.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer).  That does two things.  It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist.

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` for your `activity` in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: he wants when he turns his device horizontally. will it work for portirate.

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed the orientation of the emulator?  It defaults to portrait for phones, and if you put the layout in layout-land, it won't be used in portrait mode.

`Ctrl-f11` and `ctrl-f12` will toggle the orientation of the emulator on a windows machine (while the emulator is in the foreground).

Comment: yeah thank u very much..
but do i need to change something in the code part also..?

Comment: You shouldn't.  Normally you create two layouts with the same name (so you don't have to change any code).  One (for portrait mode) goes in the `layout` directory, the other (for landscape mode) goes in the `layout-land` directory.  Other than that no code necessary (unless you have different elements in each one instead of just a re-arrangement of the same ones).

Answer (score 1):

For changing your emulator from landscape to portrait & viceversa use CTRL+F11.